# Order Confirmation email intermittent totals alignment issue

Tags: magento-1.6, transactional-mail, order-confirmation

Recently our **order confirmation emails** have started to have an **issue**. Intermittently we will have an email where the Subtotal, Shipping, Discount and Grand Total will align left instead of right. I can't figure out what could be causing this to happen as there is nothing to indicate any kind of consistency with the problem.
Has anyone else experienced this? Any help would be appreciated!

Below are two separate orders that contain the exact same order items, but the second shows the random totals alignment issue.

[image: The way the email should display]

[image: The way it displays randomly]